# Getting the BuildAgent information from a Build

Tags: .net, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

I have a IBuildDetail variable with the build information I need.

Okay, but when I check the property BuildAgent it's showing this: build.BuildAgent' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException

Then I tryed to check build.BuildController.Agents, it's nice I found the BuildAgent, but there are 7 build agents in this collection. I need only the build agent related to my build, not all build agents from that controller.

Anyone knows how to get that information? (Select a build agent name or machine name using an IBuildDetail variable)

*-> I'm using TFS2010 api and I need to what is the agent for each build*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like Duat says.
 In order to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491685/tfs-build-duration-report-by-agent) question, I had the chance to explore this.
The following worked for a given `IBuildDetail buildDetail` & access to a `IBuildServer buildService`:

```
IBuildInformation buildInformation = buildDetail.Information;
IBuildInformationNode[] buildInformationNodes = buildInformation.Nodes;
string agentUri = buildInformationNodes[0].Children.Nodes[3].Fields["ReservedAgentUri"];
IBuildAgent buildAgent = buildService.GetBuildAgent(new Uri(agentUri));
```

Comment: Magic number (0, 3) are a "no-no"!
Solution from the link you provided is far better - for example function GetBuildAgentName by Hamid Shahid

Answer (score 3):

When the build finishes you should be able to get the agent information from the Information (IBuildInformation) property of IBuildDetail. You can try getting the node with the following type:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.common.informationtypes.agentscopeactivitytracking.aspx

and fields:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.common.informationfields.reservedagentname.aspx

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.common.informationfields.reservedagenturi.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Run On Agent scope you need to have a GetBuildAgent activity that assigns the BuildAgent details to a variable of type IBuildAgent.

You can then access the properties of that variable to get access to data about the Build Agent:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildagent.aspx

Note: The default build workflow does this already.

Comment: I'm using the TFS2010 api to access the BuildAgent info. I'm not working with wwf. This is my code: 

`IBuildDetail build = ..... ;
 build.BuildAgent ...` -> It throws an exception...