# How can I determine which build agent a given build uses in TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild

I have the following query which is very useful overall, but I cannot seem to determine which build agent my build used. *Note:* - This is now working code based on the excellent help given by @Patrick-MSFT.

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("***"));
IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer) tfs.GetService(typeof (IBuildServer));
var buildDetail = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec("Team Project","Dev-CI"); 
buildDetail.MinFinishTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-2);
var buildResult = buildServer.QueryBuilds(buildDetail).Builds.Dump();
buildInformation.Nodes.Where (i => i.Type == "ActivityTracking").FirstOrDefault ().Children.Nodes.Where (n => n.Type == "AgentScopeActivityTracking").FirstOrDefault ().Fields["ReservedAgentUri"].Dump("Agent");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build will be assigned to any of the online agents. When the build finishes you should be able to get the agent information from the Information (IBuildInformation) property of `IBuildDetail`. You can try getting the node with the following type: [InformationTypes.AgentScopeActivityTracking Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.common.informationtypes.agentscopeactivitytracking.aspx) and [InformationFields.ReservedAgentName Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.common.informationfields.reservedagentname.aspx) or [InformationFields.ReservedAgentUri Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.common.informationfields.reservedagenturi.aspx)

A example code:

```
 IBuildInformation buildInformation = buildDetail.Information;
 IBuildInformationNode[] buildInformationNodes = buildInformation.Nodes;
 string agentUri = buildInformationNodes[0].Children.Nodes[3].Fields["ReservedAgentUri"];
 IBuildAgent buildAgent = buildService.GetBuildAgent(new Uri(agentUri));
```

More details you can refer a similar question: [TFS build duration report by agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491685/tfs-build-duration-report-by-agent)

Comment: I revised my question to show the answer I came up with based upon your feedback - thanks so much for the assistance.